# ios/xcode/coredata: Best way to update screens

Tags: ios, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

web programmer trying to learn ios.  I have a setup that I think is fairly common.  Table view, detail screen, add new item screen and edit item screen.

Following various tutorials, I am saving data changes to the managed object context and therefore persistent store.  That part is working okay.  However, I am trying to use the delegate pattern to cause the screens to reflect changes and the screens are not updating (neither the table view nor the detail view.)  The detail view is presented through navigation BTW and the add and edit screens are modal.

What is correct way to get screens to update?

I have tried about everything so following code from table view is just one example of what I have tried...declare table view controller as delegate and implement required methods but I a clearly missing something:

```
 @interface IDTVC : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

in .m file:

in nsfetchedresultscontroller
 self.fetchedResultsController.delegate=self;

in view will appear

[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Thanks for a clear explanation of how to do this if there is an accepted way or otherwise any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using delegates, if you're adding a row, you can use `-tableView:insertRowsAtIndexPath:`. If you're editing a row, you can use `-tableView:reloadRowsAtIndexPath:`. Add these in the delegate methods so when you add something, it triggers one of these methods.

Comment: what are the delegate methods?

Comment: Also, currently when adding rows, the first 9 appear.  After that, a new row appears but it copies the same info as the last row.  IN other words if you create rows 1...9, tableview shows 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 but then every one afterwards is 9 i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to rely on Apple's statement in the documentation that to implement the NSFetchedResultsController protocol "A delegate must implement at least one of the change tracking delegate methods in order for change tracking to be enabled. Providing an empty implementation of controllerDidChangeContent: is sufficient."

This was giving above flaky behavior i.e. it would work up to 9 and then stop updating.

The solution was to use the full complement of code from the documentation:

```
/*
 Assume self has a property 'tableView' -- as is the case for an instance of a UITableViewController
 subclass -- and a method configureCell:atIndexPath: which updates the contents of a given cell
 with information from a managed object at the given index path in the fetched results controller.
 */

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
    atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
    atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                  atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```